# Number of intersection multiplicity points .

Tags: algebraic-curves

I need help for the following problem : 
Consider $C_1 = V(F_1)$ and $C_2=V(F_2)$ be algebraic curves in $\mathbb P (\bar K )$ (where $K$ is a field,) without a common component and $F_1, F_2  \in \bar K [X,Y,Z]$ are homogenous with $\deg(F_1 ) \le \deg(F_2)$.

And let $G \in \bar K[X,Y,Z]$ be homogenous with degree  $\deg(F_2) - \deg (F_1)$.

How can i show that 
mult$_P (C_1, C_2) =$ mult$_P (C_1 , V(F_2 + G . F_1))$ .

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the definition of the intersection multiplicity.

Let's assume that $P=[a:b:1] \in \Bbb{P}^2$, and denote by $f_1,f_2$ the dehomogenizations of $F_1,F_2$ w.r.t the variable $Z$, i.e. $f_i=F_i(X,Y,1)$, with $i=1,2$.

Then the intersection multiplicity is defined as

$$
\operatorname{mult}_P(C_1,C_2)=\dim_{\overline{K}}(\mathcal{O}_{(a,b)}(\Bbb{A}^2)/(f_1,f_2))
$$

Thus we see that the intersection multiplicity of $C_1=V(F_1)$ and $C_2=V(F_2)$ at $P=[a:b:1]$ depends only on the ideal $(f_1,f_2) \subset \mathcal{O}_{(a,b)}(\Bbb{A}^2)$. But as

$$
(f_1,f_2+g \cdot f_1)=(f_1,f_2)
$$

the intersection multiplicities in question are the same.

Comment: Can you explain the definition of intersection multiplicity ? Thanks .

Comment: Dear @Theorem, what do you mean by "explain"? What exactly troubles you about its definition? Are you maybe accustomed to a different definition of intersection multiplicity?

Comment: i think i have trouble in understanding the notation . Can you tell me what $O$ denotes here ? It would be great if i can understand what the relation precisely telling me .

Comment: Dear @Theorem, $\mathcal{O}_{(a,b)}(\Bbb{A}^2)$ denotes the local ring of $\Bbb{A}^2$ at the point $(a,b)$. In this context this means that an element of $\mathcal{O}_{(a,b)}(\Bbb{A}^2)$ is a fraction $\frac{f}{g}$, where $f,g \in K[x,y]$ such that $g(a,b) \neq 0$. Think of $\mathcal{O}_{(a,b)}(\Bbb{A}^2)$ as the ring of all rational functions defined at $(a,b)$, i.e. the ring of all quotients of polynomials, whose denominators do not vanish at the point $(a,b)$.